# How to augment TypeScript interface in d.ts

Tags: typescript

My use case: request's [RequestResponse type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/fde627d9e806c47b10595a5abb82fb0b2a1b14d7/request/index.d.ts#L144) is missing the `body` property and looks like this:

```
declare namespace request {

    // ...

    export interface RequestResponse extends http.IncomingMessage {
        request: Options;
    }

    // ...

}
declare var request: request.RequestAPI<request.Request, request.CoreOptions, request.RequiredUriUrl>;
export = request;
```

I'm trying to fix it by creating a `request-fix.d.ts` file with something like this:

```
import * as http from 'http';
declare namespace request {
    export interface RequestResponse extends http.IncomingMessage {
        body: any;
    }
}
```

But it has no effect. My end goal is that in my `app.ts`, I can do this:

```
import * as rp from 'request-promise';
import { RequestResponse } from 'request';

let response = rp.get(url);

response.statusCode; // works
response.body; // doesn't compile
```

Of course I could just contribute to DefinitelyTyped :) But this question is about to augment the `RequestResponse` interface.

Comment: 1. missing `export` for RequestResponse in `request-fix.d.ts` 2. is `request-fix.d.ts` added to `files` in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: The `.d.ts` file is not producing any compile time errors even when I put nonsense there. In my tsconfig.json: `"files": ["app.ts", "request-fix.d.ts" ]`. Tried adding `/// <reference ...>` to my app.ts, no difference.

Comment: Oh `skipLibCheck` was true. That moves me forward, at least I can see some more errors..

Comment: Now the .d.ts certainly compiles but the `.body` property is still not recognized by the compiler.

Comment: Are  you trying to overwrite their `RequestResponse` type declaration file with your own version?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin No, I'm trying to augment it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the combination that works in `request-fix.d.ts`:

```
import * as http from 'http';

declare module 'request' {
    export interface RequestResponse extends http.IncomingMessage {
        body: any;
    }
}
```

To augment existing module, `declare module` must be used instead of `declare namespace`, and it must appear in the module scope somewhere among the compiled sources.

That is,  `request-fix.d.ts` must have some import at top level to turn it into a module, as you did with `import * as http from 'http'` in your code. If `declare module` appears in the non-module scope, (as I did with the first attempt at the answer), it just declares separate, unrelated module as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9748#issuecomment-232822688).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I've created this small repo to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/borekb/ts-augmentation-demo

Comment: The import must be at the top level, I've updated the GitHub demo with working solution: https://github.com/borekb/ts-augmentation-demo. (If you update your code, I'll mark it as a the answer. Thanks for your help!)

Comment: **Important note**: `declare module request` is NOT the same as `declare module "request"`. Had me puzzled for some time. (with the quotes, it tries to resolve the module to existing module matches; without, it assumes you're declaring a whole new module/namespace)

Answer (score 4):

@artem is right, +1, just wanted to add that you shouldn't forget about the namespaces.

For example, this is how you add a `className` prop to the `CardTitle` component from `material-ui`:

```
declare module "material-ui" {
    namespace __MaterialUI {
        namespace Card {
            export interface CardTitleProps {
                className?: string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The explaination is simple.. Modules and namespaces only exist in runtime and are merged automatically.