# Matrerial ui createTheme seting with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

```
 "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
 "@mui/material": "^5.2.8",
 "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.3.0",
 "@mui/system": "^5.3.0",
```

above is current version I'm using. I just want to set some custom colors.
So I wrote my theme.ts like below

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        common : {
            arcBlue: "#0B72B9"
        }
    }
});

export default theme;
```

it's giving me below error

```
Type '{ arcBlue: string; arcOrange: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<CommonColors>'.
```

this is my theme.d.ts

```
import { Theme, ThemeOptions } from '@mui/material/styles';

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface CustomTheme extends Theme {
    pallete: {
        common: {
            arcBlue: string;
            arcOrange: string;
        };
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface CustomThemeOptions extends ThemeOptions {
    pallete?: {
        common: {
            arcBlue?: string;
            arcOrange?: string;
        };
    };
  }
  export function createTheme(options?: CustomThemeOptions): CustomTheme;
```

how to use mui with typescript with that ?

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262565/how-to-augment-typescript-interface-in-d-ts